# PL/SQL creating separate lists for genders

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to print out male and female friends in separate lists using loop,  however receive the error:

'   loop
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:'

```
DECLARE
 v_gender VARCHAR2(500);
 v_male VARCHAR2(1);
 v_female VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (select * from friend_name)
        LOOP
    v_gender := 'Gender ' || i.gender ||', '|| i.first_name ||', '|| i.last_name;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_gender);
    
    v_male      := null;
    v_female    := null;  
    
    FOR J IN (SELECT * FROM friend_name)LOOP
   
             IF(j.gender = 'M')
    THEN dbms_output.put_line(first_name ||', '|| last_name ||', '|| v_male);
    
    ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line(first_name ||', '|| last_name ||', '|| v_female); 
    
             END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
```

Could you help me figure out what's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error you got is related to the fact that you didn't `END` the first `LOOP`. If you fix it, you'll get another error as you didn't properly *qualify* the `J` cursor variables (i.e. not just `first_name`, but `j.first_name`).

When fixed, with sample table:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM friend_name;

GENDER  FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAME
------- --------------- ---------------
M       Little          Foot
M       Scott           Tiger
F       Big             Feet
```

procedure *works*

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_gender  VARCHAR2 (500);
  3     v_male    VARCHAR2 (1);
  4     v_female  VARCHAR2 (1);
  5  BEGIN
  6     FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM friend_name)
  7     LOOP
  8        v_gender := 'Gender ' || i.gender || ', ' || i.first_name || ', ' || i.last_name;
  9        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_gender);
 10
 11        v_male := NULL;
 12        v_female := NULL;
 13     END LOOP;
 14
 15     FOR J IN (SELECT * FROM friend_name)
 16     LOOP
 17        IF (j.gender = 'M')
 18        THEN
 19           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (j.first_name || ', ' || j.last_name || ', ' || v_male);
 20        ELSE
 21           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (j.first_name || ', ' || j.last_name || ', ' || v_female);
 22        END IF;
 23     END LOOP;
 24  END;
 25  /
```

and produces this output:

```
Gender M, Little, Foot
Gender M, Scott, Tiger
Gender F, Big, Feet
Little, Foot,
Scott, Tiger,
Big, Feet,

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I have no idea whether that's what you really wanted as you didn't post desired result, but - consider something like this:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_male    VARCHAR2 (10000);
  3     v_female  VARCHAR2 (10000);
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR i IN (SELECT gender, first_name, last_name FROM friend_name)
  6     LOOP
  7        IF i.gender = 'M'
  8        THEN
  9           v_male := v_male || ', ' || i.first_name || ' ' || i.last_name;
 10        ELSIF i.gender = 'F'
 11        THEN
 12           v_female := v_female || ', ' || i.first_name || ' ' || i.last_name;
 13        END IF;
 14     END LOOP;
 15
 16     v_male := LTRIM (v_male, ', ');
 17     v_female := LTRIM (v_female, ', ');
 18
 19     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Male: ' || v_male);
 20     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Female: ' || v_female);
 21  END;
 22  /
Male: Little Foot, Scott Tiger
Female: Big Feet

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Or, maybe using collections?

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_male    SYS.odcivarchar2list;
  3     v_female  SYS.odcivarchar2list;
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name
  6       BULK COLLECT INTO v_male
  7       FROM friend_name
  8      WHERE gender = 'M';
  9
 10     SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name
 11       BULK COLLECT INTO v_female
 12       FROM friend_name
 13      WHERE gender = 'F';
 14
 15     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Male:');
 16
 17     FOR i IN v_male.FIRST .. v_male.LAST
 18     LOOP
 19        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_male (i));
 20     END LOOP;
 21
 22     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Female:');
 23
 24     FOR i IN v_female.FIRST .. v_female.LAST
 25     LOOP
 26        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_female (i));
 27     END LOOP;
 28  END;
 29  /
Male:
Little Foot
Scott Tiger
Female:
Big Feet

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

There are various options (as usual).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parameterised cursor and then loop for each gender:

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_friends (v_gender IN VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT * FROM friend_name WHERE gender = v_gender ORDER BY first_name, last_name;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('M');
  FOR f IN c_friends('M') LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(f.first_name ||', '|| f.last_name ||', M');
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('F');
  FOR f IN c_friends('F') LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(f.first_name ||', '|| f.last_name ||', F');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

or you can use a cursor to find the distinct genders and then use a parameterised query to find the names for that gender:

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_friends (v_gender IN VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT * FROM friend_name WHERE gender = v_gender ORDER BY first_name, last_name;
BEGIN
  FOR g IN (SELECT DISTINCT gender FROM friend_name ORDER BY gender DESC) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(g.gender);
    FOR f IN c_friends(g.gender) LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(f.first_name ||', '|| f.last_name ||', '||g.gender);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or, if you only need to display the names then you don't need to use multiple cursors; instead, just order the query by gender:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_gender VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  FOR f IN (SELECT * FROM friend_name ORDER BY gender DESC, first_name, last_name) LOOP
    IF v_gender IS NULL OR v_gender != f.gender THEN
      v_gender := f.gender;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(f.gender);
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(f.first_name ||', '|| f.last_name ||', '||f.gender);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE friend_name (gender, first_name, last_name) AS
SELECT 'F', 'Alice', 'Abbot' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'M', 'Bobby', 'Baron' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F', 'Carol', 'Count' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'M', 'David', 'Duke'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F', 'Emily', 'Earl'  FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> ```
> M
> Bobby, Baron, M
> David, Duke, M
> F
> Alice, Abbot, F
> Carol, Count, F
> Emily, Earl, F
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4fWRjjDm)